# How to check if there are there img tags only in a paragraph or or at the end of the paragraph

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

how I can check if there are img tags only in a paragraph or or at the end of the paragraph?

```
$input = '<p><img src="#" /></p>'; // ok
$input = '<p><img src="#" /><img src="#" /></p>'; // ok
$input = '<p>xxx<img src="#" /></p>'; // ok

$input = '<p><img src="#" />xxx</p>'; // NOT ok

if(preg_match("/img/$", $input) { ... };
```

Any other better methods than `preg_match` and `regex`?

Comment: Did you make a first attempt yourself? The regex you provided is not even close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument), and check if there are any text contents on the `<p>` node:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $input);

$p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$children = $p->childNodes;

$img_found = false; $error = false;

foreach( $children as $child) {
    if( $child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE && !$img_found) {
        // Text before the image, OK, continue on
        continue;
    }
    if( $child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        // DOMElement node
        if( !($child->tagName == 'img')) {
            // echo "Invalid HTML element found";
            $error = true;
        } else {
            $img_found = true;
        }
    } else {
        // echo "Invalid node type!";
        $error = true;
    }
}

// No errors and we found at least one image, we're good
if( $img_found && !$error) {
    echo 'ok' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'NOT ok' . "\n";
}
```

You can see in [this demo](http://3v4l.org/r942U) that is passes all of your tests. It fulfills the requirements:

1. Only images and text inside the `<p>` tag. Any other tags, are invalid. If this is untrue, modify it for your needs.
2. If there is text, it must come before we detect an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Way better than a regex but unfortunately it does not catch the third example (text followed by image).

Comment: This doesn't discount other non-text HTML elements (not that I can think of any that are likely to be present inside a p tag :P), and doesn't take into account the fact that other elements are OK as long as they are at the end of the p tag.

Comment: @Jeroen - My first answer was quick as my test server was offline, I've updated my answer with a codepad demo.

Comment: @Maccath - It now takes into account all nodes, however any node that's not a text node and an `<img>` tag is invalid according to the specifications provided by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
/<p[^>]*>.*<img[^>]*></p>/
```

Explanation:
If you want to match a tag with unknown attributes with regex you can use `<TAGNAME[^>]*>`. The expression `[^>]*` matches every character zero or n times besides `>` , thus accepting any numbers of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
if (preg_match("/<img\s[^<>]*><\/p>/i", $input) { ... };
```